# Установка Parallel STL на Ububtu 16.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, parallel

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как установить Parallel STL на Ubuntu 16.04
пробовал по инструкциям от сюда 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-pstl
с использованием этого репозитория
https://github.com/intel/parallelstl
В интернете информации нет (или может плохо искал, если так, то тыкните носом). Кто-то может уже ставил или знает как ставить, пожалуйста объясните.

Comment: И какие результаты? На каком этапе у вас загвоздка и какая?

Comment: Ни на каком, я думаю
Склонировал репозиторий и пошел по по пути 
 `/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_<version>` Но директории с таким именем(/opt/intel/) не было, поэтому попробовал выполнить скрипт
`pstlvars.sh` из директории, в которую склонировал репозиторий, но, естественно, ничего не произошло, он просто выполнился и всё. Тогда я сам создал директорию
`/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_1/linux/pstl/bin` и исполнил скрипт там, но он также просто выполнился и всё, ничего больше не произошло. Что ещё можно сделать не знаю, прошу помощи.

Comment: Странно, что скрипт не выводит ошибки. Вы установили Intel TBB? И вы уверены, что ничего не произошло? Тестовые примеры не собираются?

Comment: Да, Intel TBB установлена
Не собираются не то что тестовые примеры, но компилятор не видит даже просто подключенные библиотеки
`#include "pstl/execution" , #include "pstl/algorithm"`
В директории `/usr/include` не появляется `/pstl`. Пробовал закинуть руками из репозитория, кидает ошибки по типу:  
      `/usr/include/pstl/internal/parallel_impl_tbb.h:37:2: error: #error Intel(R) Threading Building Blocks 2018 is required; older versions are not supported.`
     `‘tbb::this_task_arena’ has not been declared`          
Хотя отдельно Intel TBB работает нормально, всё выполняется.

Comment: Так, с этим вопрос решен
Нужно было попросту поставить новую версию Intel TBB.
Но теперь возник ещё один вопросик:
при сборке некоторых стандартных примеров вылезает это:
  `undefined reference to tbb::interface7::internal::isolate_within_arena(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&, long)'`
Почему эту функцию не находит я не понимаю, в сети ничего подобного, опять же, не нашел.
Если есть варианты, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Использовал -L и теперь всё собирается     
`g++ pstl_ex.cpp -std=c++11 -ltbb -L/opt/intel/tbb/4.4/lib/intel64/gcc4.7/ -o ps`
 но при попытке запустить код (./ps):  
`#include "pstl/execution"
#include "pstl/algorithm"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
 std::vector<int> b(10000000);
    std::fill_n(std::execution::par_unseq, b.begin(), b.size(), -1);
}`вылетает это
`./ps: symbol lookup error: ./ps: undefined symbol: _ZN3tbb10interface78internal20isolate_within_arenaERNS1_13delegate_baseEl`
Что с этим делать?

Answer (score 2):

Ставил PSTL, используя GitHub репозитории [PSTL](https://github.com/intel/parallelstl) и [TBB](https://github.com/01org/tbb). ОС - Debian 9.4. После клонирования репозиториев я собрал TBB с помощью `make tbb -Bj compiler=clang`, подсорсил `tbbvars.sh` и пошёл в PSTL репозиторий.

Проверил `env | grep TBBROOT` - ОК, есть TBB

Проверил `env | grep LD_LIB` - OK, есть TBB

Подсорсил `pstlvars.sh intel64 auto_pstlroot` (`auto_pstlroot` добавил, чтобы автоматически определилась `PSTLROOT`).

Проверил `env | grep PSTLROOT` - OK, есть PSTL

Запускаю билд теста `make test_for_each -Bj compiler=clang` => `undefined reference to tbb::interface7::internal::isolate_within_arena(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&, long)`

Проверил построенную библиотеку на этот символ `nm -gC libtbb.so.2 | grep isolate` => `00000000000228c0 T tbb::interface7::internal::isolate_within_arena(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&, long)` => символ есть.

Понял, что что-то идёт не так.. Проверил перечень всех установленных библиотек на системе через через `/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep tbb` и увидел следующее:

`libtbb.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2`

`strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2 | grep TBB` => `TBB: VERSION     4.3` => похоже, используется старая библиотека.

Поглядел символы, что торчат из неё: `nm -gCD /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2 | grep interface7`=> не увидел символа, который искался при сборке PSTL теста.

Видимо, Debian лез в первую очередь в системные библиотеки и только потом пытался пойти по LD_LIBRARY_PATH библиотекам, находя сначала старую TBB, без нужного символа. Добавил явно: `make test_for_each -Bj compiler=clang LDFLAGS=-L<*путь до tbb библиотеки, что я сам построил*>`. Всё завелось!

> Использовал -L и теперь всё собирается g++ pstl_ex.cpp -std=c++11 -ltbb -L/opt/intel/tbb/4.4/lib/intel64/gcc4.7/ -o ps но при попытке запустить код (./ps): #include "pstl/execution" #include "pstl/algorithm" #include  #include  #include  int main() { std::vector b(10000000); std::fill_n(std::execution::par_unseq, b.begin(), b.size(), -1); }вылетает это ./ps: symbol lookup error: ./ps: undefined symbol: _ZN3tbb10interface78internal20isolate_within_arenaERNS1_13delegate_baseEl Что с этим делать?

Добавьте путь до библиотеки в LD_LIBRARY_PATH - должно заработать.